# Installing Ubuntu on an HP Spectre 360x - advice needed

Tags: hp

I recently purchased an HP Spectre 360x, and I'm planning on installing Ubuntu.

1. Has anyone done this before, and did they encounter any problems?
2. Will Ubuntu be able to handle the 4K screen, with the desktop environment and apps scaling properly so things don't look ridiculously tiny?
3. How well does Ubuntu work with a touch screen, or which flavor of Ubuntu should I get in order to be able to take advantage of the Spectre's touch screen capabilities?

**Edit:** I remembered I have a bootable USB drive containing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I'm currently trying it out on the laptop. I had to set some scaling options for menu bars and icons, but it's working fine. While individual touches do work as a mouse / click thing, swiping with a touch highlights rather than scrolls, and attempts at using multi-touch gestures to zoom do nothing. Is there any way to enable multi-touch gestures / touch-and-drag scrolling?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Find the answers below:

1. None. I too am using Ubuntu from a long time as in from 2 years and I didn't face any issues till date.
2. Yeah, why not. It works fine on my dell laptop giving me no resolution or display issues.
3. It works great. I am using a combination of Ubuntu with Win-10 on a touch supportable dell laptop and I have till date not faced any issues. I am able to enjoy all touch facilities available without hassle. Also, I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Will have to check bro for this multi-gesture thing. Will let you know about it.